# XSLT foreach complex condition

Tags: html, xml, xslt, foreach

I want to transform the below xml to html using xslt.

horder - represent row position of element

vorder - represent column position of element

rows - total no. of rows present inside the element

columns - total no. of columns present inside the element

```
<Page>
  <Sections>
    <Section id="parent_hdr_sec" haschild="y" layout="hbox" rows="2" columns="1" horder="1" vorder="1">
      <Sections>
        <Section id="plan_hdr" layout="vbox" rows="1" columns="6" horder="1" vorder="1" />
        <Section id="plan_hdr_dtl" layout="vbox" rows="1" columns="5" horder="2" vorder="1" />
      </Sections>
    </Section>
    <Section id="splitter_sec" haschild="y" layout="vbox" rows="1" columns="2" horder="2" vorder="1">
      <Sections>
        <Section id="parent_left_sec" haschild="y" layout="hbox" rows="4" columns="1" horder="1" vorder="1" />
        <Section id="parent_right_sec" haschild="y" layout="hbox" rows="7" columns="1" horder="1" vorder="2" />
        <Section id="parent_left_sec_1" layout="hbox" rows="1" columns="6" horder="2" vorder="1" />
        <Section id="parent_right_sec_1" layout="hbox" rows="1" columns="5" horder="2" vorder="2" />
      </Sections>
    </Section>
  </Sections>
</Page>
```

Need HTML output:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td id="parent_hdr_sec">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td id="plan_hdr"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td id="plan_hdr_dtl"></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="splitter_sec">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td id="parent_left_sec"></td>
               <td id="parent_right_sec"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td id="parent_left_sec_1"></td>
              <td id="parent_right_sec_1"></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Kindly help me to build XSLT for the above one...Need suggestions regarding this..

My XSLT:

```
 <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <table>
          <xsl:for-each select="Page/Sections/Section">
            <tr>
              <td  id="{@id}">

                <table>
                  <xsl:variable name="Rows" select="@rows"/>
                  <xsl:variable name="Columns" select="@columns"/>
                  <xsl:variable name="Layout" select="@layout"/>

                  <xsl:if test="$Layout = 'hbox'">
                    <xsl:for-each select="Sections/Section[$Rows >= position()]">
                      <tr>
                        <td id="{@id}">
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                  </xsl:if>

                  <xsl:if test="$Layout = 'vbox'">
                    <tr>
                      <xsl:for-each select="Sections/Section[$Columns >= position()]">
                        <td id="{@id}">
                        </td>
                      </xsl:for-each>
                    </tr>
                  </xsl:if>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
```

I used the above XSLT using foreach condition and getting output like this

My Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<html>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td id="parent_hdr_sec">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td id="plan_hdr" />
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td id="plan_hdr_dtl" />
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="splitter_sec">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td id="parent_left_sec" />
              <td id="parent_right_sec" />
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Downvoting, because you haven't explained where you got stuck. You're just asking people to write the code for you, rather than explaining why you can't write it yourself.

Comment: @MichaelKay Im new to XSLT so only stucked here...Sorry for not posting my XSLT code at first...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like another grouping questions to me.
It assumes that both @horder and @vorder are unsorted.

@horder in your example is sorted, which means you can get rid of the inner loop

**XSLT 2.0 solution**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>


<xsl:template match="//Page">
<html>
<body>
 <xsl:apply-templates select="Sections" />
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Sections">
<table>
   <xsl:for-each-group select="Section" group-by="@vorder">
            <xsl:sort select="@vorder"/>
            <tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                    <xsl:sort select="@horder"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current()" />
                </xsl:for-each>  
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
</table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Section">
<td>
   <xsl:attribute name="id" select="@id" />
      <xsl:attribute name="horder" select="@horder" />
   <xsl:apply-templates select="Sections" />
</td>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XSLT 1.0**
I used Muenchien grouping, but note that @vorder is not unique in the entire dataset, so I concatenated it with generate-id of parent node.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="section-by-vorder" match="Section" use="concat(generate-id(parent::*), @vorder)" />

<xsl:template match="//Page">
<html>
<body>
 <xsl:apply-templates select="Sections" />
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Sections">
<table>
   <!-- select first Section from each group -->

   <xsl:for-each select="Section[count(. | key('section-by-vorder', concat(generate-id(parent::*), @vorder))[1]) = 1]">
            <xsl:sort select="@vorder"/>
            <tr>
                <!-- for all contacts in a group -->
                <xsl:for-each select="key('section-by-vorder', concat(generate-id(parent::*), @vorder))">
                    <xsl:sort select="@horder"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current()" />
                </xsl:for-each>  
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
</table>
</xsl:template>



<xsl:template match="Section">
<td id="{@id} horder={@horder} vorder={@vorder}">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="Sections" />
</td>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks @Lesiak for the reply..actually I am using xslt 1.0...so for-each-group is not recognized. Can you please suggest in xslt 1.0

Comment: @Hari Please post your XSLT code and describe the issues you have encountered. We are not a code writing service that "suggests" solutions that you can copy-and-paste. Some effort from your end that goes beyond *"here is my input and this is the output I want"* is actually required here.

Comment: From review: @Hari, the way to say that answer helped you is making it the "Accepted answer" or upvoting or both. Editing answer with "thank you" and your results is a wrong way.

Comment: @Hari That's all-right, just remember to include your attempt with your next question. :)